# Responsive two column layout (list and details panel)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I create a responsive two column layout with the left column displaying a hit list and the right column (details panel) showing the details of the item selected in the list?

- The list items should have a (relatively) fixed width whereas the details panel should use all of the remaining space.
- Both columns should be scrollable.
- There should be some empty space on both sides of the layout.
- At the top of the page there should be a fixed search area.

[image: UI mock-up]

EDIT: This is what i have so far...:

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="center">
  <header>
   <input type="text" placeholder="search...">
  </header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/1">
     <h3>Headline 1</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/100/nature/1">
     <h3>Headline 2</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="details">
   <p>
    ...
   </p>
   <p>
    ...
   </p>
   <p>
    ...
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```html
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:1%;
    width: 98%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    left: 1%;
    top:10%;
    width: 29%;
    min-width: 120px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height:90%;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
#details{
    position: fixed;
    right: 1%;
    top:10%;
    width: 69%;
    background-color: #fff;
    height:90%;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
#center {
 width: 100%;
 overflow-y:hidden;
 }

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #fff ;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}


ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0; 
}
 
h3 {
 font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
 
li img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
 
li p {
  font: 200 12px/1.5 Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
}
 
li {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
 
li:hover {
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Problem: How can I remove the white vertical strip representing the 'main' vertical scrollbar? And I'd like to add a left and right margin to the the two columns.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Simply Google "responsive two column layout" and there are loads of methods. Also, what do you explicitly mean by 'responsive'? What do you want to change, and when?

Comment: Jaunt, the width of the details panel should adapt to the screen size. And when the screen gets too narrow it would be nice if the details panel could be displayed below the respective list item. Apologies for asking silly questions

Answer (score 0):

With simple html and css this can be done, however, I assume you need it to be dynamic.

My example is very basic, but this is what you're aiming for I guess but I'm not making your design, you should do it yourself.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <input type="text" placeholder="search...">
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Hit 1
        </li>
        <li>
            Hit 2
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="details">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:1%;
    width: 98%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: green;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    left: 1%;
    top:10%;
    width: 19%;
    min-width: 120px;
    background-color: red;
    height:90%;
}
#details{
    position: fixed;
    right: 1%;
    top:10%;
    width: 79%;
    background-color: blue;
    height:90%;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Jesse, thanks for your reply. I'll give it a try...!

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this with basic HTML and CSS.

Its on similar lines as the above solution:

The code would be of the following parts:

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive Two Page Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id= "search">
<span id="searchSpan">
    <input type="text" value="" id="searchtext" placeholder="Search"/>
</span>
</div>
<div id="cols">
    <div id="hitList">
        <ul id="list">
            <li><a href="A.html" target="details">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="B.html" target="details">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="C.html" target="details">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="A.html" target="details">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="B.html" target="details">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="C.html" target="details">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="A.html" target="details">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="B.html" target="details">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="C.html" target="details">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="A.html" target="details">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="B.html" target="details">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="C.html" target="details">C</a></li>

        <ul>
    </div>
    <div id="detailsPanel">
        <iframe name="details" id="details" src="" frameBorder="0" >
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    #searchtext{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1em;
    height: 3em;
    border-color: black;
    border:1em;
    margin:0.5em;
}
#search{
    border-color: black;
    border:solid;
    width:100%;
    height:4em;
}
#searchSpan{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1em;
    border-color: #000;

}
div#cols{
    width:100%;
    margin:0.5em;

}
#hitList{
border-color: black;
border: solid;
width: 20%;
float: left;
height: 10em;
overflow: auto;
}
div#detailsPanel{
    border-color: black;
    border:solid;
    height: 10em;
}
ul{
    padding: 0em;
    margin:0em;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
    line-height: auto;
    border:solid;
    padding:0em;
    border-width:0.1em; 
}
```

The links would point to a different HTML pages A'B and c etc which would be displayed in the details panel.

I used an iframe instead of Div aas displaying web pages on iframe is easier than on div(This is my opinion and it can be corrected.)

This is a very basic solution which I churned out quickly and needs enhancement.
Hope this helps !